# Is it a good practice to make low quality links un-crawlable to increase link juice?

Tags: seo, links, backlinks

Is it a good practice to make low quality links un-crawlable for search engine spiders? Usually we put `nofollow` but that divides link juice.  We would like to increase link juice to all other do-follow links?

if yes, is there special JavaScript that we should use?

Comment: You can only control your own links on your own site. The best advice is to do an audit periodically and remove links low value pages or sites. Otherwise, for links to your own site that are spammy the only recourse is to disavow them, however, even lousy links can have value. It takes a seriously abusive situation for links to be considered toxic (a term Google does not use). That is why serious consideration must be given before disavowing a link or site. One link is not generally a problem, but hundreds or thousands from a single site can be.

Comment: @closetnoc thanks for the comment and useful information. But I am only questioning about only my own links(internal or external) on my own site( or on-page seo )

Comment: Internal links are different in influence than external links. Internal links can be sculpted (a reasonable and necessary processes) to give better value. It is just a matter of when and how we link in a hierarchical/organizational fashion. External links, however, are more binary since they are not organizational but referential. Either they are of value or not. Remember that links often carry some value. Keep in mind that the PR6 page with 2 links does not actually pass PR 3 per link. This model was never true. Just make the best links you can that makes sense and forget the rest.

Comment: BTW- This is a rather broad topic. Is there something specific - a scenario you have in mind?? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to worry about lost link juice for internal links.   You "lose" link juice when you use nofollow or when you link to something in *robots.txt*.   Many sites do one or the other of those with a large number of links on each page and yet they continue to rank just fine.

I've experimented with this before.   I've tried to hide links from Googlebot so that Googlebot conserves every ounce of Pagerank.   It doesn't help.

My theory is that Google uses internal links to assign a weight to each of your pages and then scales those weights by your domain rank.   "Losing" internal Pagerank ends up not mattering because of that scaling factor.

Writing links with JavaScript won't even help these days.   Googlebot does a great job of parsing JavaScript and can render pages just like a real browser does.   Googlebot would be able to see any links created by JavaScript just as well as normal HTML links.